# Part of my Texture doesn't bake

Tags: uv, texture-baking, baking

So i had a few issues with texture baking recently and I couldn't find a solution. The Issue was that the Texture was distortedor and part of it didn't bake. So I tried my texture in a new project on a cube. All sides of the cube are assigned to the texture exept for one.
Here is the result.[image]

As you can see all sides are correctly baked execpt for one which is just white. As if Blender ignored that side of the cube.
Maybe it's a problem with my material so here is the material in the node editor.
[image]

It feels like something is wrong with my Blender or I don't know about an option which would fix that.
It is new Project so no modifiers.
I am new to blender and i don't have too much experience so I hope sombodey could give me an advice.

Comment: Does every part of it have the material you try to bake with?
Does it have any overlapping UV's or are these the default Cube UV's
You also should not bake with margin that high if the faces are not far enough apart from each other

Comment: One side of the cube isn't assigned to the material and these are the default Cube UV's. There shouldn't be any overlapping Uv's. I also tried to set the margin to 0 and 4  but that didn't seemed to change it.